# Aggregate By Column in SQL That Results in Sample Size and % with Case When

Tags: sql, presto, trino

Hi I have a table in SQL (presto) that has the following format:

```
uuid    group_name    transaction_id      sales       device      is_local
 xyz       control              123x         11          ios         false
 abc     treatment              124x         12      android          true
 def       control              125x         13      android         false
 ghi     treatment              126x         14          ios         false
 jkl       control              127x         15          ios          true
 mno     treatment              128x         16      android         false
```

how do I write a query where if there were 100 devices I can get the total sample within the group name and the percentage of each device within the group name?

I want my final table to look like this based on the device column:

```
attribute    control_sample    treatment_sample    score_control    score_treatment
      ios               100                  50              0.5               0.33
  android               100                  50              0.7               0.40
   tablet               100                  50              0.3               0.80
       TV               100                  50              0.6               0.20
```

this is the attempt originally but it did not give me the output I wanted:

```
device AS (
  SELECT
    device AS attribute,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN group_name = 'control' THEN 1 END) AS control_sample,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN group_name = 'treatment' THEN 1 END) AS treatment_sample,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN group_name = 'control' THEN 1 END) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE group_name = 'control') AS score_control,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN group_name = 'treatment' THEN 1 END) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE group_name = 'treatment') AS score_treatment
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY device
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `sum` [window function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) over the grouping results:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(uuid, group_name, transaction_id, sales, device, is_local) as (
    values ('xyz',       'control', '123x', 11,          'ios',         false),
        ('abc',     'treatment', '124x', 12,      'android',          true),
        ('def',       'control', '125x', 13,      'android',         false),
        ('ghi',     'treatment', '126x', 14,          'ios',         false),
        ('jkl',       'control', '127x', 15,          'ios',          true),
        ('mno',     'treatment', '128x', 16,      'android',         false)
)

-- query
select attribute,
    control_sample,
    treatment_sample,
    control_sample * 1.0 / sum(control_sample) over () score_control,
    treatment_sample * 1.0 / sum(treatment_sample) over () score_treatment
from (
    select device attribute,
        count_if(group_name = 'control') control_sample,
        count_if(group_name = 'treatment') treatment_sample
    from dataset
    group by device);
```

Output:

| attribute | control_sample | treatment_sample | score_control | score_treatment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| android | 1 | 2 | 0.3 | 0.7 |
| ios | 2 | 1 | 0.7 | 0.3 |

But the problem with your query was (as far as I can see) is that you got struck by another case of integer division (i.e. 999/1000 is 0 when both operands are of integer type), so you can fix it by multiplying one of operands by 1.0 - for example `COUNT(CASE WHEN group_name = 'control' THEN 1 END) * 1.0/ (SELECT COUNT(*) ...) AS score_control`

Comment: This is great thanks - is it possible to add a case when statement to this? For example, I want to add logic where if the attribute = iphone then it is also ios. When I try this it fails to aggregate it: `case when (device = 'iphone' or device like '%ios%') then 'ios' else device end as attribute,`

Comment: @nak5120 yes. Update the inner select with corresponding code.

Comment: got it thanks. I needed to also add the logic to the group by - I couldn't just call attribute: `group by (CASE WHEN device = 'iphone' then 'ios' else device end)`

Comment: @nak5120 tbh not following. If you can explain the goal? You want to keep the device name but use something else for grouping or counts?

Comment: I wanted to add additional logic to categorize the device names. For example, if the device is labeled as `iphone` then 'ios' if the device is 'droid' then 'android' etc. To add this additional layer I needed to add it to your inner select and additionally in the group by of the inner select since presto cannot group the label by itself, attribute

Comment: the code works, just wanted to add an additional layer and was curious how to do it

Comment: this is the new code: `select attribute,
    control_sample,
    treatment_sample,
    control_sample * 1.0 / sum(control_sample) over () score_control,
    treatment_sample * 1.0 / sum(treatment_sample) over () score_treatment
from (
    select CASE WHEN device = 'iphone' then 'ios' else device end attribute,
        count_if(group_name = 'control') control_sample,
        count_if(group_name = 'treatment') treatment_sample
    from dataset
    group by (CASE WHEN device = 'iphone' then 'ios' else device end))`

Comment: @nak5120 you have several options, 1st one is to do just `group by 1` which will alias first select column or just do another subselect, or better use CTEs with `with`.

Comment: oh good call! Group by 1 is much easier thanks

Comment: @nak5120 Just small FYI - note that it considered by some devs to be a a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question I think you were quite close to the solution. Please note that if you divide an integer by an integer you will get an integer result, and you need decimals. I suggest the following:

```
SELECT
      t.device AS attribute
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN t.group_name = 'control' THEN 1 END) AS control_sample
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN t.group_name = 'treatment' THEN 1 END) AS treatment_sample
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN t.group_name = 'control' THEN 1 END) / MAX(g.group_count) AS score_control
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN t.group_name = 'treatment' THEN 1 END) / MAX(g.group_count) AS score_treatment
FROM your_table AS t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
          group_name
        , count(*) * 1.0 group_count -- "convert" to decimal by the * 1.0
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY
          group_name
    ) AS g ON t.group_name = g.group_name
GROUP BY
        t.device
```

| attribute | control_sample | treatment_sample | score_control | score_treatment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| android | 1 | 2 | 0.33333333333333333333 | 0.66666666666666666667 |
| ios | 2 | 1 | 0.66666666666666666667 | 0.33333333333333333333 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sMDnIRc2)